# AWS API Gateway Error - [429] Maximum number of Request Validators for this API has been reached

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, limit, serverless-framework, request-validation

I am using AWS API Gateway request validation feature for my APIs. You can check more details in the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-request-validation.html).
To deploy the API, I am using the serverless framework. Following is a snippet from the **serverless.yml**.

```
resources:
  Resources:
    ParameterRequestValidator:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator
      Properties:
        Name: ParameterRequestValidator
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        ValidateRequestBody: true
        ValidateRequestParameters: false
```

The endpoints are backed by lambda functions and are defined as follows:

```
functions:
  configs-create:
    handler: src.handlers.configs.create.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /configs
          method: post
          cors: true
          reqValidatorName: ParameterRequestValidator
          request:
            schema:
              application/json: ${file(src/handlers/schemas/config_create.json)}
```

As of now, I have 8 entities with 5 endpoints for each REST method - POST, GET ID, GET All, PUT, PATCH. Out of these, the request validator has been attached to the methods POST, PUT and PATCH. Hence, **there are total 24 endpoints that use the request validator.**

On running serverless deploy, I get the following error message:

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  An error occurred: ApiGatewayMethodMeasurementDashlocationsIdVarPutValidator - Maximum number of Request Validators for this API has been reached. (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 429; Error Code: LimitExceededException; Request ID: xxxx; Proxy: null).
```

The [Quotas Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#api-gateway-control-service-limits-table) page does not mention a specific limit on the number of Request Validators.
Also, I intend to have more methods, however, seems like I have already hit the limit with 24 functions using the request validator.

**How can I get around this limit and ensure the serverless deploy command does not fail? Also, does anybody know how many request validators are allowed?**

Help would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update: I have tried with 18 functions using the Request validator - it works fine. It also does not throw any error for 20. When I add the 21st method using the request validator, it throws the above error. So, it seems like only 20 request validators are allowed per API.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: @balderman I have completely ditched using the request validator. I have included jsonschema validation in my handler code itself through a common function. jsonschema is available as a module for Python and Node.js too.

Comment: Thanks... it is much more cleaner (in my eyes) if AWS API GW will do the validation for me. This is why I dont put this logic in the Lambda code.

Comment: That's true, but the request validator limit is a hard limit and 20 is too less when you have a lot of APIs. It will work if you are able to create a few validators and reference the same ones in multiple APIs. Serverless framework have fixed this issue now, here is a link https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/9291

Comment: ShwetaJ - thanks